# Can "expertises" as a plural form be used?

Tags: plural-forms, uncountable-nouns

I've seen [here](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=872653) that there is no plural of expertise, so what should I do in the following sentence?

> the different expertise is/are complementary.

To put into context, we have a multidisciplinary consortium with partners of different "expertise" (or maybe skills is a better word)

Stated more generally, can a "mass noun" be a subject? If yes, can I put the verb in plural to show that it is used as a plural?

From your answers, it looks like I should completely reformulate my sentence. Should I really avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say you employ people within different areas of expertise, or people with varying skill sets.

Your example phrase lacks a bit of context, but I could imagine it flowing somewhere around these lines, including the notion of expert(ise) and skill sets in one sentence:

> When you decide to hire the services of our experts, their wide variety of skill sets is complementary.

Comment: thank you for the quick solution provided. I like the "varying skill set". However, I would like to know if/how I can use my sentence (or a similar sentence in another context)

Comment: @radouxju I added a suggestion to my answer

Answer (score 7):

Here's my recommendation: **Use *expertises***. Don't be confused by what you've read in that thread.

You've managed to come up with a sentence where *expertise* needs to be pluralized. You are talking about two or more distinct kinds of expertise that complement each other.

I have no problem with:

> In order to perform well in this job, the manager needs expertise in management, programming, scheduling, and testing. These different **expertises** are complementary.

If you're not bold enough to pluralize *expertise*, you can get around the problem by saying:

> In order to perform well in this job, the manager needs expertise in management, programming, scheduling, and testing. These different **kinds of expertise** are complementary.

Some times ago, there was a similar debate on ELU about the [plural of *equipment*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70828/what-is-the-plural-of-equipment). In that case, the debate got rather heated, because the user didn't provide any legitimate example construct where *equipments* might be a better word.

As one extra note to those who remain unconvinced, who stand ready to click the downvote button: Ignore those red squiggly lines from your spell-checker! There is [ample](https://www.google.com/#q=%22the+expertises%22&tbm=bks) [precedent](https://www.google.com/#q=%22other+expertises%22&tbm=bks). Read on:

> *Often in putting together a new combination they lack specific **expertises**, and in the pressure of competition they do not have time to develop them in-house*.
>   <sub>(from the book *The Nature of Technology: What It Is and How It Evolves*, by W. Brian Arthur, 2009)</sub>
>
> *These four **expertises** – that of the educator, the political orator, the judge, and the general – oversee aspects of that moral life itself, which the statesman regulates overall*.
>   <sub>(from the book *Reason and Emotion: Essays on Ancient Moral Psychology and Ethical Theory* by John Madison Cooper, 1999)</sub>

There is even one book – ironically entitled [*Rethinking Expertise*](http://books.google.com/books?id=gQpmyyYPc4IC&source=gbs_navlinks_s) – that begins by defining a "Periodic Table of Expertises":

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Altought the use of "skill sets" from @oerkelens was a good workaround, this is the type of answer I was looking for.

Comment: This is a well-researched and explained answer but I would argue that "areas of expertise" is much more common than "expertises".

Comment: @starsplusplus - You would get no argument from me. The start of my third sentence (_"You've managed to come up with_...") was meant to indicate that this is a [relatively rare case](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=expertises%2Careas+of+expertise&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15) – which, when you think about it, makes this question all the more interesting.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I meant that it would be more common to use "areas of expertise" in a sentence like this ("the different areas of expertise are complementary"). Are you saying "areas of expertise" can't be used here? If so, please explain.

Comment: @starsplusplus - No, I'm not saying that "areas of expertise" can't be used, or shouldn't be used here – there's not enough context to know for sure which wording would be best. Based on how the O.P. asked the question, though, I assumed that "expertises" would be the better word to use, but the O.P. was reluctant to do so, because, "there is no plural of expertise, so what should I do?" My answer refutes that erroneous assertion, saying, "Yes, there **is** a plural of expertise, and, if that's the best word to use, then by all means use it." However, I wouldn't use the plural word very often.

Comment: @J.R. Thanks, that's clearer now. I understand where you're coming from.

Comment: The countification of 'expertise' has still (2024) not been recognised by OLD, CD, Collins etc. This and ngram searches indicate its use is rare. A workaround is better as it sounds more natural.

Answer (score 2):

You are right. The word *expertise* is a mass noun.

> [Expertise](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/expertise?q=expertise) (mass noun) - *expert skill or knowledge in a particular field.*

You can say:

> Services by experts from different areas/fields/domains are complementary.

If you want to use *expertise* anyhow:

> The service from the expertise from different domains is complementary.

Comment: Or, the O.P. could just use _expertises_. See my answer.